# compiler warning on (ambiguous) method resolution with named parameters

Tags: c#-4.0, named-parameters

One question regarding whether the following code should yield a compiler warning or not (it doesn't). It declares two methods of the same name/return type, one has an additional named/optional parameter with default value.

NOTE: technically the resolution isn't ambiguous, because the rules clearly state that the first method will get called. See [here, Overload resolution, third bullet point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739(VS.100).aspx). This behavior is also intuitive to me, no question.

```
public void Foo(int arg) { ... }

public void Foo(int arg, bool bar = true) { ...} 

Foo(42); // shouldn't this give a compiler warning?
```

I think a compiler warning would be kind of intuitive here. Though the code technically is clean (whether it is a sound design is a different question:)).

Comment: why do you have a default parameter on the 2nd method? as your link states, if you call Foo(42) it should call the first method, so your second method with default param will never get chosen...?

Comment: The problem isn't that I design a class with these two methods. The problem is imperfect world, I add the second method to the class when the first already exists (which I may be unaware of), add the call, probably miss the (slow) Intellisense, and wonder why the new one doesn't get called. Not a big issue, but a potential issue nevertheless. And to me it is close enough to being an ambiguity.

And if you tell me you have never accidentally implemented something twice, then you have never written code in a complex project.

Comment: @oedo, the question here is not about the default parameter, but why does the compiler emits no warning in this scenario. The problem is that the developer might not be aware of this rule.

Comment: ah i see, sorry. yes in that case i agree with you, a warning would keep the principal of least surprise.

Comment: Calling Eric Lippert ... (http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert)

Comment: what's the question? whether it should emit the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree that it needs a warning, actually. The main issue is, that code is *potentially* legitimate, and if that's the case you would have to explicitly disable the warning.

What I mean is, in general when you get a warning, you will be able to change your code to get rid of the warning (and presumably make the code better at the same time). But in this case, it may be that you did it like that intentionally and would not be able to change your code to get rid of the warning.

For example, the "unreachable code" warning is something you can just delete the unreachable code to get rid of the warning. Or the "could not find reference" warning - this is usually a signal that you're going to get "undefined type" errors, but if not then you can simply delete the reference. Or maybe "A previous catch clause already catches all exceptions" warning: in this case, you need to change your code so that either the new clause comes before the catch-all, or remove the catch altogether.

But the point is that in every case when you get a warning, you *should* change your code, and making the change will always result in "better" code. However, in the case of this question, the call is not ambiguous (as far as the compiler is concerned) and I don't think you can argue that it's *always* a mistake to write code like that, so therefore there shouldn't be a warning.

If the compiler issued a warning about *every* case where you do something that's probably not the best idea, then we'd be inundated with warnings!

Comment: Maybe there should be a Code Analysis rule for this ... couldn't find one. Extension methods (which in my eyes is a much less severe case) behave the same way in terms of resolution and (absence of warning). However I do feel the problem I asked about is way more severe of an issue than unreachable code.

Comment: Yeah, I think it'd be a good candidate for fxcop or somesuch.

Comment: Is there any point in doing this intentionally? Since the default value for the second parameter will never be used, that makes it redundant code.

Answer (score 1):

Warnings are to notify programmers of potentially dumb mistakes.  This is an area that could generate a dumb mistake, so yes, it should generate a warning.  Are you trying to form a petition?